# usage of "yet to be"

Tags: phrases, word-usage

Can I say

> He is yet to be a murderer.

to mean the he is not a murderer, but very soon he will be one?

Comment: Hmm, but would you apply that same lawyerly-mumbo jumbo nuance to the much more common wording "He is not a murderer, yet" or "He is not yet a murderer"? At least in casual North American English, such sentences would have embedded within them a strong expectation that he would eventually become a murderer. I can follow the legalistic, lawyer-B.S. denial in @Robusto's comments, but would that also be the case in these much more common examples? I am curious...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this could be construed to mean something different, depending on context. It could actually be a rejection of the notion that the person mentioned is or will be a murderer.

For example,

> Mr. Johnson may be many things, many of them unpleasant: a career criminal, a liar, a deadbeat husband. But he is yet to be a murderer.

This means that whatever bad things he has done, he has stopped short of murder. It is the kind of statement a defense attorney might make in a trial on behalf of his client. Sure, he's a bad man, but he's not a killer.

Comment: I agree. It's a great point and definitely valid when it comes to language and I even think I've heard it in the context of law before, but now when I stop to think about it, it sounds awkward. I don't see this coming positively towards the guy. Somehow it implies, in myself at least, that he is planning on murdering someone. Either way, I agree with this answer.

Comment: Agree with both of you. You and I are not murderers (AFAIK). But Mr Johnson is not a murderer -yet.

Comment: I think Mr Johnson should sack that lawyer. However, with someone like an investigator who is not on Mr Johnson's "side", but who still doesn't believe him guilty of that particular crime, it could be more reasonable. I do think this answer lacks that in other contexts the phrase is much more open to the suggestion that he would indeed murder at some point.

Comment: The idiom in American English is _have yet to `VP`_, as in _He has yet to [be beaten at chess/conquer the summit of Aconcagua/try the really **hot** sauce]_. The idiom means _have not yet VP_, and is negative, as can be seen by the fact that _yet_ is a [negative polarity item](http://wwwl.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler Apparently the *is yet to* form shifted places with the *has yet to* idiom with the latter taking the lead around 1930. See [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+yet+to%2C+has+yet+to+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: @bib: Almost certainly all that NGram reflects is an increase in constructions like *the best is yet to come*. If you include *"he"* in the search terms, you'll see that, as John says, [he **has** yet to](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+is+yet+to%2Che+has+yet+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) is overwhelmingly the dominant form (and becoming *more* so, not less).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I though I was agreeing with John as the ngram shows. *is* has yet to regain its former glory.

Comment: @JohnLawler: While I agree that *has* is what I would use, I don't see any problem with using *is* there. Hell, Browning used it: *Grow old along with me / the best is yet to be*—and while you may object that there is no object in that example, I don't think adding one is off limits. So I am yet to be convinced.

Comment: @Robusto: It's not a matter of saying you *can't* use "[be] yet to be" - just that it's been [well out of fashion](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+am+yet+to+be%2CI+have+yet+to+be&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) for the past century. OP's context seems contrived to me, and your interpretation would normally be expressed as *"he **has** yet to be **accused of being** a murderer"*, I think.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I know that, but it's beside the point, and your NGram doesn't prove what you think it does.

Comment: @Robusto: You're a mine of information. What was I expecting it to show, and why am I mistaken?

Comment: I didn't really consider the _be yet to_, and in any event the distinction between official _has_ and official _is_ gets lost in most speech, so it's likely there's a dual idiom with _be_ for every one that starts with _have_. I agree with Robusto about that. It may or may not go out of fashion in print; but some people are hearing -- and therefore saying, and often writing -- _be_ instead of _have_. And it's not going to change in speech as long as it's heard.

Comment: @John: My impression (which it seems to me was backed up by NGrams) is that *be yet to* was more popular in the past. Granted, the distinction is lost with things like *He's yet to be tested in battle*, but it's unavoidably still there in first person singular, for example. And to me at least, *I **am** yet to be tested in battle* sounds decidedly "dated" by comparison with the ***have*** version.

Comment: _I_ and _I'm_ are almost indistinguishable, and one tends to say or hear _I'm_ far more frequently. That gives it a different distribution than 3rd person. Plus, of course, NGrams are writing only, and indifferently spelled, punctuated, and tagged, so, to the extent this reflects a real trend in real spoken language, it's going to show a lot of distortion, because the occasions and skills for writing that phrase are not the same as those for speaking it. Especially an archaic construction.

Answer (score 5):

The word *[yet](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/yet)*, when used as an adverb, means that something has not occured at a particular point in time

> up until the present or a specified or implied time; by now or then:
>   *I haven’t told anyone else yet*
>   *aren’t you ready to go yet?*
>   *I have yet to be convinced*

In each of the examples, there is a connotation that the situation is likely, or at least potentially, about to change.

Most US speakers would read the example given to mean

> He is yet to be a murderer [but I am not sure how long that innocence will last].

If I were to proclaim proudly

> I have yet to cheat on my spouse

my wife would take it ill. She expects nothing less than

> I have not cheated on my spouse, *or better yet*
>   I would never cheat on my spouse.

Answer (score 4):

Robusto's answer shows the valid present interpretation of 'is yet to be' - how can one possibly be certain what is yet to be or what someone is yet to do (unless one is a prophet).

However, there is the possibility of using the present tense to refer to a historical event or time interval:

In 1928, Hollywood is yet to be discovered by the Marx Brothers.